# Use npt.NDArray[np.uint64] to query pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-typing

I'm trying to understand how to properly use type annotations with pandas and numpy. I have a DataFrame indexed with an index of dtype `np.uint64`. I want to write a function that returns a subset of this DataFrame in the following way:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1, 2, 3]), index=np.array([10, 20, 30], dtype="uint64"))
assert df.index.dtype == np.uint64


def get_NDArray(df: pd.DataFrame, key: npt.NDArray[np.uint64]):
    df2 = df.loc[key]
    reveal_type(df2)
    return df2
```

With annotation `key: npt.NDArray[np.uint64]`, it doesn't work. In *pyright*, the inferred type of `df2` is `Series[Unkown]`, which is incorrect (should be `DataFrame` instead). In *mypy*, it says

```
error: Invalid index type "ndarray[Any, dtype[unsignedinteger[_64Bit]]]" for "_LocIndexerFrame"; expected type 
"Union[slice, ndarray[Any, dtype[signedinteger[_64Bit]]], Index, List[int], 
Series[int], Series[bool], ndarray[Any, dtype[bool_]], List[bool], 
List[<nothing>], Tuple[Union[slice, ndarray[Any, dtype[signedinteger[_64Bit]]], 
Index, List[int], Series[int], Series[bool], ndarray[Any, dtype[bool_]], 
List[bool], List[<nothing>], Hashable], Union[List[<nothing>], slice, 
Series[bool], Callable[..., Any]]]]"
```

I can change the annotation of `key` to `key: np.ndarray` or `key: npt.NDArray`, and then everything works correctly, but I want to be sure that `key` is not an arbitrary `np.ndarray`, but `np.ndarray` with `dtype == 'np.uint64'`. I expected that `npt.NDArray[np.uint64]` is exactly the tool that should allow that, but it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of `pandas-stubs` for [`_LocIndexerFrame`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/blob/v1.5.2.230105/pandas-stubs/core/frame.pyi#L154), which is the type returned by the `loc` property, shows that the `__getitem__` method accepts (among other irrelevant options) the [`IndexType`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/blob/v1.5.2.230105/pandas-stubs/_typing.pyi#L189), which is a type alias for a union of (among other things) [`np_ndarray_int64`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/blob/v1.5.2.230105/pandas-stubs/_typing.pyi#L183), which happens to be yet another type alias for `numpy.typing.NDArray[np.int64]`.

This corresponds to the output you got from `mypy` mentioning the `ndarray[Any, dtype[signedinteger[_64Bit]]]` type in that gigantic union of types.

To be fair to you, because these packages are so bloated, proper type annotations result in huge monstrosities of type unions everywhere. So it is not so easy to dig through them or type checker output for them. But that is another story...

Anyway, the `NDArray[np.uint64]` you want to use is **not a subtype** of `NDArray[np.int64]` because `np.uint64` is **not a subtype** of `np.int64` (and the [`ScalarType`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.25.0.dev0/numpy/_typing/_generic_alias.py#L238) is covariant). I believe their closest common ancestor is `numpy.core.integer`.

The `DataFrame.loc` object expects to be subscripted with an array of **signed** integers.

I don't know enough about pandas, but I believe negative integers as indices for [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) are not a problem, so this is not that surprising. Now, whether or not this means that the annotations are incomplete (oh boy...) or passing unsigned integer types will actually lead to some unexpected behavior down the line, I have no clue.

This is just the explanation of the error you encountered. Changing the annotation of `key` to `npt.NDArray[np.int64]` should fix it.

Comment: Thanks! I opened an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/issues/508) on pandas-stubs. Let's see what the developers think about it.